# Angular 2 way binding doesn't work with template even though I'm not using primatives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I can't figure out what's wrong with my code. I'm following the example of this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h5aac/94/) in order to bind the two inputs. What I'm trying to do is just a little more involved- I'd like to load a certain template based on an attribute passed into the directive. I can't figure out what's wrong over [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LuvXk/90/).

This is my html

```
<!-- template -->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="X-template.html">
<button ng-click='clickMe()'><b>Check model</b></button>
Directive: <input ng-model="this.test"></input>
</script>


<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <my-directive type="X"></my-directive>
    No Directive:<input ng-model="this.test"></input>
    {{this.test}}
</div>
```

And my JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.this= {test : "asdf"};

    $scope.clickMe = function() {
        alert($scope.this.test);
    }
}

app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        compile: function(element, attrs) {
            element.append('<div ng-include="\'' + attrs.type + '-template.html\'"></div>');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with trying to use `this`, which is a reserved keyword in JavaScript, as a property name.

Try using a different property name. I changed your example to use `foo` in the link below.

http://jsfiddle.net/01h3ne4y/